# Receiving an AJAX response in Node.js local server

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, mongodb

I am succesfully posting an AJAX Post request to my MongoDB.

**However I cannot seem to grasp how to receive back a response.**
I scoured for info and I got the impression that this has to do with the same-origin policy when running a local server.

I am trying to log the `code` that is sent via Ajax in the console.

**PS:** I am a complete beginner in Node.js.

---

Here is my code in **users.js file**

```
router.post('/adduser', function(req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    db.collection('userlist').insert(req.body, function(err, result){
        res.send(
            (err === null) ? { msg: '',code:'1234' } : { msg: err }
        );
    });
});
```

And this is the Ajax call in **global.js file**

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: newUser,
            url: '/users/adduser',
            dataType: 'JSON'
        }).done(function( response ) {

            // Check for successful (blank) response

            if (response.msg === '') {
                 console.log(response.code);
                // Clear the form inputs
                $('#addUser fieldset input').val('');


                // Update the table
                populateTable();

            }
            else {

                // If something goes wrong, alert the error message that our service returned
                alert('Error: ' + response.msg);

            }
```

Comment: Is the `done()` callback executing at all, if not add a `fail()` callback to see what's wrong!

Comment: @adeneo Yes it is..I've tried logging the msg instead of code,  console.log(response.msg),  and I just get an empty string back in the console. I changed the msg from '' to '1234' and I still get back an empty string.

Comment: Sorry had to restart the server, should I close this down for being too stupid? I'm guessing another fool might do the same and find a solution here so I'm a bit hesitant

Comment: That's up to you, but I would just close it!